# Basename a file name with spaces and using filename with spaces in command 1

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I am new to shell scripting, and having some issues. I can't figure out how to save filename in variable and using them in commands.

I am trying to look for file paths of specific extension, then save

1. filename

in $name variable and use information to run identify to check width and height of the images.

for the error based on code below, i get

1. `identify: unable to open image ~/PATH/name`
2. `identify: unable to open image ./with`
3. `identify: unable to open image ./spaces`

and if i do echo $name to check if the name was saved correctly, i get

1. `name`
2. `with`
3. `spaces.jpg`

is there any way that the command takes full file name with spaces ? simply double quoting the variable seems not helping.

(I've done `name=$(basename "$a")` already with the double quotes. also `width=$(identify $a | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d 'x' -f 1 )` does not work too)

```
for a in `find "$dir" -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" \)`;do
    name=$(basename "$a")

    directory=$(dirname "$a")
    #echo "$name"
    width=$(identify "$directory/$name" | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d 'x' -f 1 )
    height=$(identify "$directory/$name" | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d 'x' -f 2 )
```

Comment: `for` has already performed wordsplitting. `find ... | while IFS= read -r a; do` is better, though still fails if filenames can contain newlines

Answer (score 1):

thx to @jhnc, there is below a portable solution (**EDIT** see comments):

```
find "${directory}" -type f \( -name \*.[Jj][Pp][gG] -o -name \*.[Jj][Pp][Ee][gG] \) -exec sh -c '
  for a ; do
    name="$(basename "${a}")"
    directory="$(dirname "${a}")"
    # printf "%s\n" "${name}"
    width=$(identify "${directory}/${name}" | cut -d " " -f 3 | cut -d x -f 1 )
    height=$(identify "${directory}/${name}" | cut -d " " -f 3 | cut -d x -f 2 )
    # other ....
  done' sh {} +
```

### for history

Maybe asking `find` to terminate the filenames found with the null character, using `-print0` would make it more robust. This option corresponds to the `-0` option of `xargs`.

Give a try to this (**EDIT** see comments):

```
find "${directory}" -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.jpeg \) -print0 |\
 xargs -0 bash -c '
   for filename; do 
     bname="$(basename "${filename}")" ;
     dname="$(dirname "$filename")" ;
     printf "%s\n" "${bname}" ;
     # ... other treatments ...
   done' bash
```

.

Comment: note that these options are nonstandard although quite commonly available. I believe the portable way is to use `find`'s `-exec ... +` option: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_18

Comment: eagle eyes: thx -> the answer had been modified.

Comment: @jhnc I never noticed that ```-print0``` was no portable, and much more : __considered but not adopted__ by the open group.
Then a solution with ```-exec ``` still need to be provided

Comment: I added one but deleted it - the question already uses non-portable find option `-iname`. The exec version simply changes `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` to `find ... -exec ... {} +`

Comment: @jhnc it would have been interresting. Is the find below more standard?
```find "${directory}" -type f -a \( -name \*.[Jj][Pp][gG] -o -name \*.[Jj][Pp][Ee][gG] \) -a -exec ...```

Comment: Seems ok (using `-a` is optional), but it shows why the `-iname` option was invented!

Comment: @jhnc, I tried a porrtable version. Any comment?

Comment: Use `+` not `';'`, otherwise `for` is pointless and you invoke a new shell for every file which is less efficient. Right side of `=` does not have to be double-quoted (although it is safe to do so). The original (and thus this) code splits path into dir/file but then recombines on use (so could just use `"$a"` directly). Presumably they are used later. `identify` has a `-format` option but that's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @jhnc thx for the ```+```. Good to know about the right side of the ```=```. The rest was left unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use a `while read` instead of the `for` loop:

```
find $directory -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" \) |
while read a
do
```

However you do it, the spaces need also to be taken care of in the `identify` command - as you have it, the cutting of space-delimited fields won't work right. I suggest:

```
    let `identify -format "width=%w height=%h" "$directory/$name"`
```